# Angular Directive: does one-way binding property (@ or &) create watch behind the scene

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

When i create a custom directive with isolated scope, and use @ or & for one way binding.
Does a watch being created for each of these properties?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Suppose you have in your template,

```
<div drink flavor="strawberry"></div>
```

or

```
<div drink flavor="{{rootFlavor}}"></div>
```

and in your JavaScript code of the drink directive,

```
scope:{flavor:"@"}
```

then if you look in the source code, you will see that this is done:

```
isolateScope.flavor=$interpolate(attrs.flavor)(scope)
```

which in the first case comes down to

```
isolateScope.flavor=attrs.flavor
```

Comment: In nodeLinkFn. There are the  cases: '@', '=', '&'. In case '=" there is a watch function. The compile process of the template is split in two phases: compile and link. In the compile phase the directives are build and the tree of nodeLinkFn's. In the link phase the root scope is given to the root nodeLinkFn, and the whole tree is walked down. For every node maybe scopes, controllers are created, and the link functions are called which you program in your directives.